# How to test port by telnet command on localhost?

Tags: windows-xp, port, localhost, telnet

I have windows Xp , I want to test some port , someone advice me to use telnet command on localhost to test it . but i don't know how i can do it (syntax of telnet command on local host) ?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by executing the Command Prompt (Start -> Run -> cmd)

Once you get the command prompt you can test the port by writing this on the command prompt

```
telnet localhost PORTNUMBER
```

Comment: I assume you're trying to test the HW port - if so, this may not get you what you want.  I don't know Windows networking as well as another OS, but the OS will likely short circuit the data path and never actually hit the hardware.

Answer (score 4):

on win 7 i found why telnet not work.

go to

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features

Then click on `Turn Windows features on or off`  on left side panel and checked `Telnet Client` and `Telnet Server`.
after click OK, you can use this in `windows command prompt (cmd)`.

Answer (score 1):

to learn some of the syntax from the command prompt type:

```
c:\telnet /?
```

Typically you would do something like the following and see what kind of message pops up. Sometimes it may connect but nothing gets displayed. If the port is closed, then there is an error of some kind... even if nothing displays in a couple of seconds, just type "quit" to close the connection.

```
c:\telnet IPAddrOrHostname Port#
c:\telnet 192.168.0.1 25
c:\telnet server.mydomain.com 80
```

Comment: getting response - Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Comment: on localhost getting socket exception error while testing the app on real devices, how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [install telnet client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) by using [DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh824821.aspx) command:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

or:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

Then run:

```
telnet example.com 80
```

where `example.com` is your destination host (can be `localhost` for local PC) and `80` is the port number.

When you connect, to disconnect, hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, then type `quit` command to exit.